# Intune Graph API - assigning groups to Powershell script returns success but is not assigning the group(s)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, intune

Calling the Intune Graph API devicemanagementscriptgroupassignment create method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-devices-devicemanagementscriptgroupassignment?view=graph-rest-beta) is returning success but the group(s) are not getting assigned.

Once the call to the Intune Graph API devicemanagementscriptgroupassignment create method executes, you can go into the Intune portal (browser) under endpoint.microsoft.com->Devices|Windows->Windows|PowerShell scripts->NameOfPowerShellScript and verify that it is not working by looking at the Assignments (at the bottom of the page).

Unfortunately, it does not always fail...it is intermittent.

The code where the issue occurs is function Add-DeviceManagementScriptAssignment (line 250) from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/blob/master/DeviceConfiguration/DeviceManagementScript_Add_Assign.ps1

Comment: What is the status code in the response when it fails?  When it fails are you getting only one item instead of an array?  You can force a singleton to an array by surrounding with @($data)

Comment: Sorry, the first hyperlink should go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-devices-devicemanagementscriptgroupassignment?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: The status code is always success (the call is surrounded with a try-catch and the catch never gets executed).

Comment: The issue must be the data since you are always getting 200 ok.  You need to capture good and bad data and determine the differences.

Comment: There are only 2 values that you pass to the Graph API: 
1. The $ScriptId 
2. The $TargetGroupId
The code checks for nulls on each of these.
Of course, when I test, it is working...just not for a production customer.
I will continue troubleshooting...thanks